# Alternitive for Ajax success?

Tags: javascript, ajax, if-statement

I am currently working with multipule ajax requests and I ran into a problem. Currently, this is what I have:

```
var x = true;
var RanThroughEverything = false; 
while(x){
  if(ButtonWasClickedByUser){
     ajax{
        //send ajax request and get response;
        success: function(res){ 
             if(res == "What I want it to equal"){
                 x = true;
             }
             else{
                 x = false;
             }
        }
     }
  }
  else{
    x = true;
  }
  if(SecondButtonWasClickedByUser){
     ajax{
        //send second ajax request and get response;
        success: function(res){ 
             if(res == "What I want this one to equal"){
                 x = true;
             }
             else{
                 x = false;
             }
        }
     }
  }
  else{
    x = true;
  }

  x = false;(To break out of function)
  RanThroughEverything = true; 
}
if(x == false && RanThroughEverything){
   alert("One");
}
else if(x == false && RanThroughEverything == false){
   alert("Two")
}
```

The problem I am having is that no matter what I set the res (or result) of the success function to equal to, it always alerts One. I figured out this is because to get a response from ajax takes time, and by that time, the while loop would have been broken by the x = false nearing the end of the while loop. Is there any way that the ajax responses can register before one iteration of the while loop is complete?

Comment: instead of a while loop which my guess from the code is an infinite loop until user clicks things.. use a click event -> run ajax call -> update dom, and repeat for other button, when both were clicked and good then do something else (alert).

Comment: you could also use a queue which reacts to placing things in an array https://playcode.io/634360/

Comment: Unfortunatly, that is not possible to do because the way my page is designed is it is a huge form, and whenever the form is submitted, this chunck of code will run and it will see which buttons you have clicked, take the values of the form, and pass them to ajax. For more clarification, a button adds extra questions to the form. So unfortunately, this solution is out of the question (pun intended).

Comment: @LawrenceCherone This seems interesting but I am still confused as to how this would relate to soliving the problem at hand. For further clarification, the problem I am facing is that js skips over checking if the result is okay because it is taking too long and then just outputs that it works no matter what

Comment: yeah that while loop is looping about 500k times a second, as mentioned dont use a while loop, there is no fix to this code it needs rewriting to use a condition on the previous state (how you define the state could be though dom or saved variable from previous ajax call)

Comment: Ok I will take out the while loop and re-write the code. Thank you for the advice and for the help @LawrenceCherone, I really appreciate it.